# Add class or other attribute using media query

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, media-queries

I'm currently using CSS media queries to target some small/medium screen devices like this:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
  ...
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 720px) {
  ...
}
```

This works as expected, and I can apply styles to some particular selectors, but.. What I was wondering is if there is a way to add a class or other attribute to a selector based on media query.

Example of my thought:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
  body { addClass('body-iphone') }
}
```

Is there a way to do that with CSS or maybe JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801224/jquery-add-class-dynamically-depending-on-the-browser-window-resolution - this sounds like solving your issue

Comment: @Daniel, almost yes, but it only works for all devices (desktops too), i would like to find a way to use `min-device-width` to make sure this isn't just a small 13" laptop screen

Comment: well then, you should also check the user agent. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). Lightweight, pure JavaScript library for handling media queries. Looks pretty cool.

Comment: this is something similar to what i needed! i'm simply voting for this because it can do anything in the callbacks, uses media queries, and has fallbacks for older browsers.. what else do we need!

Answer (score 8):

It cannot be done with plain CSS.

Have a look at LESS or SASS. They are designed to make **working with** CSS more dynamic and flexible.

- http://lesscss.org
- http://sass-lang.com

Once you use them. You can't live without them.

---

In case you want to add a existing class selector to the body on certain resolutions.

#### SASS

```
.some-style { background-color:red; }

@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
        @extend .some-style;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how would you add the 'body-iphone' class to body tag using LESS/SASS and without javascript ? ..

Comment: Well ok for that, but you're not answering the question. This does not add a class to the body tag, it's just applying the css of an existing class to the body tag.

Comment: @Bixi I never did say you could add a actual class to the body node with styles. My approach is practically the same. The only real difference is that javascript would add a actual class to the node's classList and this doesn't. It just applies the style which in most cases should suffice.

Answer (score 5):

A JavaScript solution

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-device-width: 480px)").matches) {
    // modify dom
}
```

Edit:missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

take a look at conditionizr this could be what your looking for http://conditionizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

For this also can help [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) - can detect even if svg enabled or other features is enabled.

http://modernizr.com/