# make accordion on mobile view bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my app there are too many contents. In the Review section there are lots of reviews and I need to make that `div` an accordion in mobile view. How can I do that?

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1> Heading </h1> 
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 center-margin float-none no-padding">
        <div class="padding-left-30">   
            <span class="pacifico pull-left padding-right-15" style="font-size:30px;">This is the best Color ever!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-left-30 padding-top-15 quote">
            <P class="padding-top-15">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, explicabo? Vero voluptate harum explicabo possimus facilis aliquam iusto voluptatibus eos aspernatur ducimus velit, est. Non quos ab perspiciatis nobis possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam cum officia quae voluptatem voluptates illo mollitia velit consequatur rerum error molestiae maiores, iusto ab natus excepturi animi alias, quam sit?</P>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-right-15-per padding-top-15">
            <p class="pull-right text-bold">Basheer Shahul</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 center-margin float-none no-padding">
        <div class="padding-left-30">   
            <span class="pacifico pull-left padding-right-15" style="font-size:30px;">This is the best Color ever!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In System view it Should show's like a content, in mobile view it should change it as accordion.

col-xs and col-sm on this view content should change as Accordion.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: In System view it Should show's like a content, in mobile view it should change it as accordion.

col-xs and col-sm on this view content should change as Accordion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, have you try to follow that example ?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

All you need is add add the classes at the right place ("in" on a collapse mean he's open by default), here's a jsfiddle example for your code :

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6389/

```
<div class="col-xs-12 panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingZero">
        <h1 calss="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseZero" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseZero">
            Heading
            </a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 center-margin float-none no-padding panel-collapse collapse in"  id="collapseZero" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingZero">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="padding-left-30">   
            <span class="pacifico pull-left padding-right-15" style="font-size:30px;">This is the best Color ever!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-left-30 padding-top-15 quote">
            <P class="padding-top-15">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, explicabo? Vero voluptate harum explicabo possimus facilis aliquam iusto voluptatibus eos aspernatur ducimus velit, est. Non quos ab perspiciatis nobis possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam cum officia quae voluptatem voluptates illo mollitia velit consequatur rerum error molestiae maiores, iusto ab natus excepturi animi alias, quam sit?</P>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-right-15-per padding-top-15">
            <p class="pull-right text-bold">Basheer Shahul</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In System view it Should show's like a content, in mobile view it should change it as accordion.

col-xs and col-sm on this view content should change as Accordion.

Comment: if you want different style depending on the media you should use media queries http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: In your case what you want is more add a class if media is mobile, but you'll probably need to add a bit of javascript for that (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15022888/3703099 )